# Passing username and password in ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, cross-domain

I want to send a username and password in an ajax call. I realize its a not a good practice. But for testing at the time being, I have to do that.

My code so far:

```
$.ajax({
    url: $(this).attr('action'),
    type: 'POST',
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    data: {username: "user", password: "password"},
    success: function(data){
    //var data = JSON.parse(jsondata);
    console.log(data);
    },
   });
```

But I run into 401 error everytime. Is there a way I can fix it?

Answer (score 4):

username and password for http authentication has their own fields

```
$.ajax({
    url: $(this).attr('action'),
    type: 'POST',
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    username: "user", 
    password: "password",
    success: function(data){
    //var data = JSON.parse(jsondata);
      console.log(data);
    },
});
```

Comment: I tried this and still it throws 401 error. Could it be because the end point might have different name for username and password field?

Comment: What type of authentication does the request require?

Comment: The end point I am posting to is on https. 

I looked a little and came across http authentication like http://username:password@example.com.

Should I be doing adding that in my form action like action="http://username:password@example.com/path/to/the/end/point.html"

Comment: Try using a form with that action to see if it works.